# Finding unallocated disk space (partitioning)

Tags: filesystems, partition, parted

Another (hobbiest) sys admin on they same system as me,
pointed out that there is 30Gb of unallocated space on the system.
I have need of that space to create a new partition. (I'm going to make a fast scratch for HPC)
Unfortunatly he never told me which of the many many devices on the system it was on. 
I think it might be on a pair of raided disks.

How can I find what unpartioned space exists on a system, accross all of its disks?
I can do it one dist at a time with `parted`. (by cycling though each device using `select /dev/sda` , then `print free`) but that will take a while with the many disks and is a inelegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
for disk in /dev/sd[a-z]; do
  parted $disk print free |
  grep -q "Free Space" && echo "unallocated space on $disk"
done
```

You might need to adjust the path `/dev/sd[a-z]` to fit your needs.